# SBS2003 R2 - certificates

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2003, windows-sbs

I get a log error OAL GENERATOR 9323.

Seems some users have invalid certificates, however, when opening the tab in the user properties under the Global Adress lists preview option. Active directory reports that it cannot op the certificate archive.

ERROR ---
Source: MSExchangeSA
Category: OAL Generator 
Event-id: 9323

Entry '###### ######- Search & Co Groep' has invalid or expired e-mail certificates.  These certificates will not be included in the offline address list for '\Global Address List'.
- Default Offline Address List

How can I resolve this when I cannot delete the certs? Anyone? :)

Answer (score 1):

Cant you just renew the certificates? in the CA on the server, just select the certificate assigned and choose renew?

No CA?
Here's one who seemed to be able to resolv the problem.
http://www.jasonslater.co.uk/2009/08/18/dealing-with-exchange-server-2007-oal-generator-events-9320-9323-9325-and-9327/

Comment: Thanks! I've googled and googled for it. But without success. I knew I had to remove the certificates, however non where shown! +1

Comment: Did it solve anything or are you still having the issue?